# JBOSS EAP 6.2 submodules

Tags: java-8, jboss-eap-6

I am going through a rough time implementing my design. Basically it is a web service which has 3 layers. Interface, Business logic and Back end connection service. I need to refer a jar file in module by another module jar. Is it possible? and how this can be achieved?

If I explain more, there is a modules called "Transactions", "Gateway" and "Utility". Both Transactions and Gateway are using Utility. Interface calls Transactions. Then Transactions calls Gateway.

I am using Java 1.8 and JBOSS EAP 6.2

Comment: Is this deployed as an EAR or is each a separate deployment?

Comment: All the modules are deployed seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [class loading](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) documentation (the link is for WildFly, but it works the same in JBoss EAP 6.x). You can setup deployment dependencies by referencing the `deployment.Transactions.war` dependency.

Comment: I tried this setup with JBOSS AS 7 and it was successful. Transactions, Utility and Gateway are built as Jar files and added as modules to JBOSS. only the interface web service is in deployment folder. I have already read that documentation and added the modules as a global module. Anything else to be done?

Comment: Oh, so these aren't deployments but modules add to the `$JBOSS_HOME/modules` directory? If that's the case could you add the `module.xml` files and any error messages you're seeing.

Comment: Yes that is the case.below is the content of module.xml file---------> 
`code`<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="lk.dialog.cg">
    <resources>     
   <resource-root path="CG_Transaction.jar"/>  
   <resource-root path="CG_ServiceGateway.jar"/>  
   <resource-root path="CG_utility.jar"/>  
   <resource-root path="velocity-1.7.jar"/>  
  <resource-root path="commons-collections-3.2.2.jar"/>  
  <resource-root path="commons-lang-2.4.jar"/>  
    </resources> 
</module>

Comment: That looks okay. Are you seeing errors or something?

Comment: I changed the module structure and separated all the modules. Then I got through one level. So now I can access upto Gateway level. But still I am getting errors when calling Utility package from Gateway. I am getting ERRORjavax/naming/NamingException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/NamingException------Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.NamingException from [Module "lk.dialog.cg.util:main" from local module loader @6aceb1a5 (finder: local module finder 735 (roots: D:\servers\jboss_for_CG\modules,D:\servers\jboss_for_CG\modules\system\layers\base))]

Comment: Which ever module has a dependency on `java.naming.*` you'll need to add a module dependency for `javax.api`.

Comment: I separated the modules and now it goes 2 levels down (from war to jar to jar) . But i need to go one level further.